# There is a way to put external images in a-frame?

Tags: dropbox, aframe, virtual-reality, webvr

my problem is, i am not able to put any file from dropbox in a-frame

i have try this

```
<a-assets>
        <img id="penguin" src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/lqnqf1ae7ygy3yh/4241745025010902126.JPG">
</a-assets>
```

than i try this

```
<a-assets>
        <img id="penguin" src="src: url(https://www.dropbox.com/s/lqnqf1ae7ygy3yh/4241745025010902126.JPG)">
</a-assets>
```

than i try this

```
<a-assets>
        <img id="penguin" src="https://www.dropbox.com/s/lqnqf1ae7ygy3yh/4241745025010902126.JPG" crossorigin="anonymous">
</a-assets>
```

than i try this

```
<a-assets>
        <img id="penguin" src="src: url(https://www.dropbox.com/s/lqnqf1ae7ygy3yh/4241745025010902126.JPG)" crossorigin="anonymous">
</a-assets>
```

than      NO ONE IS. WORKING! WHY?

Comment: Could you please change the title,  to make it clear that it's an issue with dropbox?

Comment: www.dropbox.com links refer to the Dropbox web site itself, not actual file content, and they don't allow being iframed, for security reasons.

Answer (score 1):

[a-assets](https://aframe.io/docs/1.0.0/core/asset-management-system.html#sidebar) expect URL's so they don't know what to do with the `url()` syntax . Unfortunately the console log isn't that clear - `uncaught exception: Object`.

But when you provide a link, like in the 1st and 3rd option, you get a more helpful log: `Cross-Origin Request Blocked: (...)` - which leads us to a conclusion - it's a [CORS](https://aframe.io/docs/1.0.0/core/asset-management-system.html#cross-origin-resource-sharing-cors) issue.

I found some [info](https://www.dropbox.com/developers/chooser), that only `direct links` support CORS. All you need is to change `dropbox.com` to `dl.dropboxusercontent.com`:

```
// normal link
https://www.dropbox.com/s/lqnqf1ae7ygy3yh/4241745025010902126.JPG
// direct link
https://www.dl.dropboxusercontent.com/s/lqnqf1ae7ygy3yh/4241745025010902126.JPG
```

Knowing this, we can try it in a-frame. And it [seems to be working](https://jsfiddle.net/gftruj/2prx1jud/).

---

As Greg noted, this method is not officially supported, and you probably should serve your images in a different way:

- On github / github pages.
- On a server which is able to server the asset with a CORS header
- On any server where the website is hosted (so they are under the same domain)

Comment: Note that `dl.dropboxusercontent.com` isn't officially supported. There are some official options documented here though that might work depending on one's use case: https://help.dropbox.com/files-folders/share/force-download